# Why does class method of a class object does not return the meta class?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

The following code:

```
  NSObject *a = [[NSObject alloc] init];
  Class c = [a class];
  Class meta1 = [[a class] class];
  Class meta2 = objc_getMetaClass("NSObject");
  NSLog(@"%@ %d", c, class_isMetaClass(c));
  NSLog(@"%@ %d", meta1, class_isMetaClass(meta1));
  NSLog(@"%@ %d", meta2, class_isMetaClass(meta2));
```

produce:

```
NSObject 0
NSObject 0
NSObject 1
```

More than that `[c isKindOfClass:c]` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta1` is the result of calling `class` on a value of type `Class`, i.e. the calls invokes a class method (`+ class`) – similarly the call `[c alloc]` (after the assignment to `c` in the code) would be equivalent to `[NSObject alloc]`.

The default implementation of `+ class` comes from `NSObject` and is [defined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571950-class) to simply return the class it was called on. So in the example code both `c` and `meta1` have as value `NSObject`'s `Class`.

That tells you why-by-definition `meta1` is not the meta class. If your question is why-by-design does it not return the meta class then that is a different question best asked of one of the language's designers!

HTH

Comment: I deduce that since the designers of the language did not want us to refer to classes by name when passing them as arguments (as stated in the link you provided), they had to provide a way of obtaining a reference to a class without an instance. Now why can't we do ` [self isKindOfClass:SomeClass];` that is a different question.